# SSH agent-forwarding on multiple servers

Tags: github, ssh

I will explain this issue as a story, so that as much detail can be provided as possible.

A (devops) user has generated 2 SSH keypairs:

> /user/.ssh/serverkey
> /user/.ssh/serverkey.pub
>
> /user/.ssh/github
> /user/.ssh/github.pub

This user works with 100s of different servers and they have automated that when spinning up a new server-instance, their public-key for server-management (serverkey.pub) is stored on each new instance.

This user would like access to the github-repos via their github-account and via the public-key they have stored on github.com (github.pub)

Due to not being able to provide info on their servers they will SSH into (there are 100s of them and the IP-addresses are not constant), this user cannot add details to `/.ssh/config` for the server.

The user is somewhat familiar with agent-forwarding, so they do the following:

`ssh-add /user/.ssh/github`

They then enter their pass-phrase.

What should `/.ssh/config` contain for the `/user/.ssh/github` key-pair, if anything?

Should the user still add something like:

```
Host github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/user/.ssh/github
```

or will not adding anything be fine?

I have personally tested this myself by not adding anything to the `/.ssh/config` file and ran this command:

`ssh -T git@github.com` on the remote-server and it worked/connected.

I am just verifying if I should add anything to the `/.ssh/config` file, just to make sure I am doing everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> will not adding anything be fine?

No, you need to specify the private key in a `.ssh/config` file (and I would put the full path of the key instead of relying on `~`)

If `ssh -T git@github.com` works without, check *where* openssh finds its key with `ssh -Tv git@github.com`: by default, it is `~/.ssh/id_rsa`.

Answer (score 0):

First -- this question should probably be moved to server-fault.

Either way, if you want the user to have access to his `.ssh/github` across any server in the cluster you describe, then this is what you should do:

For each server, under that users' directory, add the following to his ssh config (i.e. `/user/.ssh/config`)

`Host *
    ForwardAgent yes  # this will forward the ssh-agent`

Then the user simply has to add (as you mentioned) the key to his ssh-agent:  `ssh-add ~/user/.ssh/github`.

**Alternatively**, he can ssh to each instance but include the `-A` which tells ssh to do the same thing, forward the agent.  Example:  `ssh -A user@server_1; ssh -A user@server_2`, etc.   You can confirm that you have those keys available to you by calling `ssh-add -l` on every server starting with your local machine and it should be consistent.